# Pynput shows wrong mouseposition data

Tags: python, pynput

For some reason I get wrong mousepointer positions with pynput.

The 0,0 position is right and the 1920x1080 position is right but in between there is an error of around 100px.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}".format(x, y, button))


with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You're code seems to be running fine for me. How do you know that there is an error?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I had my scaling in windows at 125% (this makes eveything 25% bigger). This kinda produced the wrong position values in pynput. As I set the scaling back to 100% everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I didn't know anything to do- so I just timed all positional values by `1.25`, which gave me the dimensions: `1918, 1078`. you could use `1.25081433225` to get the exact dimension if you wish.

from pynput.mouse import Listener

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}".format(x*1.25,y*1.25,button))


with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You probably had the same issue as me. The scaling displays scaling in windows caused the values to be off. My display scaling was at 125%, so it was 1.25 off.